# Inverse cdf method for Bates distribution

Tags: math

The probability density function of a Bates distribution random variable X is
[image: pdf]

To get cdf you need to integrate pdf
[image]

I got the following cdf function:
[image: cdf]

And Inverse function:
[image: inverse function]

But this function generates wrong variates.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please make more obvious how this is a programming question. Currently it looks like a pure math question, you even tagged accordingly.

Comment: A simple way to implement the inverse CDF method is to use a numerical root finder to solve the equation F(x) = u for a given u, where F is constructed by integrating the summation term by term, or just computing the integral numerically; numerical integration will be slower, but having fewer opportunities to go wrong. An exact solution for the inverse might be possible, but a numerical approach will help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of a sum is not the sum of the inverses.

The Bates distribution with parameter `n` is the distribution of the average of `n` random numbers distributed according to the uniform distribution on (0, 1). So you can simply simulate the uniform distribution and take the average.